# How to Use Values From a Struct in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, interface-builder, struct

I Have a struct that is set up like so:

```
struct formula {
    NSString *FormulaName;
    NSString *FormulaContent;
};
```

That piece of code is in my AppDelegate Header.

Now, In my AppDelegate implementation.

```
struct formula AreaOfSquare;
AreaOfSquare.FormulaName = @"Area Of a Square";
AreaOfSquare.FormulaContent = @"A = lw";

struct formula AreaOfCirlce;
AreaOfCircle.FormulaName = @"Area Of a Circle";
AreaOfCircle.FormulaContent = @"A = 3.14*r*r";
```

This is in applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Now, how do I grab the values form these structs and use them in IB?

Thanks and sorry for bieng a n00b. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have references to your Interface Builder objects in a view controller, i.e.

```
IBOutlet UILabel* titleLabel;
```

you could just set its text directly in code:

```
titleLabel.text= AreaOfSquare.FormulaName;
```

Comment: I cnat beleive I forgot I could do that!

Comment: @AhmadGaffoor if you like this poster's answer you should accept it. And judging by the six 'Thank you!!!'s I think you liked it.

Comment: @Luke If I wanted to, could I set the text in an IBAction?

Comment: Sure, you can treat an IBAction just like other methods in the class.